# Dijkstra and grid cells?

Tags: algorithms, numerical-optimization

I have a problem with Dijkstra's algorithm. I'm trying to calculate the shortest transport time between all cells in a grid used by a general circulation model (think oceanography or meteorology). the NxN matrix of weights consists of the shortest time it takes for a particle to move from one grid cell to any other, with plenty of cells not having a connection.

My problem is that the cost to cross a cell isn't included when using Dijkstra's algortithm witch gives many jumps an advantage. Is there an alternative algorithm where you can provide a cost for the jumps between nodes?

An example:

```
   (0)
 7/   \1
(1)   (2)
1|     |1
(3)   (4)
 1\   /1
   (5)
```

The path (0) -> (1)  cost 7 with one jump
The path (0) -> (2) -> (4) -> (5) -> (3) -> (1) cost 5 with 5 jumps

I'd like to be able to provide a weighting cost for each respective extra jump in the second case.

Comment: If you add the weight $u$ to each edge the final cost of the path will be the original cost plus $u$ times the number of jumps. Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks! I had thought about that solution early on but disregarded it for some unknown reason. It should still work if _u_ varies, right?

Comment: Yes, if you increase $u$ the penalty for taking long paths will increase.